# Running a Batch file using CMD as admin through Powershell

Tags: powershell

Don't ask me why, but I'm trying to run a batch file from CMD as admin by using Powershell.  I have the following:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" `
-ArgumentList "/K cd /d C:\Users\$($User)\Desktop\Activation\'win and off 2013 act.bat'" `
-Verb "runas"
```

The CMD opens as admin, but I get an error saying that "The system cannot find the path specified."  I know it's something to do with how I've written the path to the batch file, but can't figure it out.

Comment: Why is it `$($User)` and not just `$User`?

Comment: I was having issues with getting $User to work and found that using $($User) gave me the information I needed.

Comment: But are you sure that the path is now correct? What were the issues with `$User`?

Comment: I've just changed it and I'm now getting the information for that variable in the path.  I might have had error in previous attempts that didn't make it work.  Still getting the error that the system can't find the path thou.  I think it's the way I've written 'win and off 2013 act.bat'

Comment: If a path contains spaces, the entire path must be in quotation marks, not just the portion that contains the spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment, the quotations are at the wrong place, and I just checked, and cmd would not accept single quotes anyway. So use
`"/K cd /d ""C:\Users\$User\Desktop\Activation\win and off 2013 act.bat"""`